# Php Go back to previous page form resubmit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have the following three php files:
reports.php, bwdates-reports-details.php and visitor-detail.php

reports.php contains my form which inputs the from and to date (erased some parts for brevity):

```
<form method="post" action="bwdates-reports-details.php">
  ...
<input type="date" id="fromdate" name="fromdate">
  ...
<input type="date" id="todate" name="todate">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

bwdates-reports-details.php outputs whatever parameters inputted in "fromdate" and "todate" of reports.php, see image below

[image]

As you can see in the image, there is an option to view the details of a transaction by clicking the "View Details" icon - i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x".

In view details (visitor-detail.php), There is a "Go Back" button.

```
<div align="center">
   <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
   </div>
```

There is also a goBack javascript function:

```
<script>
function goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

But when the go back button is clicked, I am getting **Confirm Form Resubmission** error. What I wanted to achieve with the "go back" button is to be able to go back to bwdates-reports-details.php with all the variables I passed through in reports.php. How do I achieve what I wanted to do? Please take note that this isn't a purchase related website. php or javascript will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desired result was achieved by using the GET method instead of POST method (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm). reports.php form code was replaced from:

`<form method="post" action="bwdates-reports-details.php">`

to:

`<form method="get" action="bwdates-reports-details.php">`

In bwdates-reports-details.php where I have the following variables:

```
$fdate=$_POST['fromdate'];
$tdate=$_POST['todate'];
```

Instead I replaced it with:

```
$fdate=$_GET['fromdate'];
$tdate=$_GET['todate'];
```

The goback javascript function I have in visitor-detail.php stays the same. And works like a charm. Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If a form is submitted (probably with the POST method), you send this data to the new page that is then opened. This page is also added to the history not only with the URL but also the sent data.

If you then leave this page and want to navigate back to this previous page you will get an "Resubmission" error, because the browser would need to send the data again to do so, but that is probaby a bad thing to do, because the data of the form would be sent twice. (Imagine that was a purchase form and the client would buy everything again.)

To make your goBack function work there are no other ways than get rid of that form submission page somehow or put a page in between that is not a form-data-receiver.
The best way would be to not go back in the browser history if you don't know from what pages the user navigated to this. Instead just navigate to an overview or dashboard.

**Edit:**

If that page your working on is only accessible by that response page of the form, maybe going two pages back will fix your error: `history.back(2);`

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mentioned that the pages are not purchases related. I indicated that now in my post.

Comment: It is not just that. It is generally prohibited by the browser for several reasons. You cannot turn off the error and force the browser to load the page via JavaScript.

Comment: @schnydszch I've made an edit to my answer; please have a look.

Comment: Hi! I'm still getting the Confirm Form Resubmission error with window.history.back(2); Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Niklas E. and Imran for having me realized that I cannot achieve this through POST method. Was able to achieve this instead with GET method. Going back reading this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm, and through your comments, it lead me to use GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 1):

Because your form is using POST method and when you click on goBack button, it goes on previous page without variables. You may use put dates variable with goBack button and also use

```
if(isset($_GET['your variable name'];
{`fetch your variables`}
```

on your previous page.